# OutputCache attribute being ignored in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, attributes

So I am having an issue with IE 7 being able to download a file from an SSL site built in MVC 3.  For IE 7 to be able to save a file from an SSL site, it must be cache-able.

The code for the method is:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "none", NoStore = true )]
public override FileContentResult Export(int? id, string extra)
{
...
return new FileContentResult(byte[], mimetype);
}
```

This working in IE9, Chrome,Safari, and Firefox.
I have tried various settings for VaryByParam, Duration and NoStore. When ever I change any of those settings the response headers never seem to change.

> Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>
> Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=PersonalInfo-02092012.xlsx
>
> Content-Length:11933
>
> Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
>
> Date:Thu, 09 Feb 2012 18:16:35 GMT
>
> Expires:-1
>
> Pragma:no-cache
>
> Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: interesting - was not aware of IEs behavior here. Yet another reason I shy away from IE now:   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this one myself but am leaving it out there so that it may be of use to someone else.

The problem was that a custom ActionFilterAttribute was manually setting the cache information and therefor the caching I was setting on the Action were being ignored.

The Attribute in question trimmed for brevity:

```
public class CustomAttributeName: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```